# TreeGrid with interactive checkbox

Tags: java, checkbox, vaadin, treegrid

Is there a way to add checkbox to a TreeGrid? (vaadin 8.1)

I tried using below code but when I select parent node, it doesn't automatically select all its child nodes.

```
treeGrid.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTI);
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you handle this yourself? Listen on the data/selection change event and then select all children as you need them?

Comment: Thank you André. How can I enable automatically children in grid?

I added this..

treeGrid.addSelectionListener(selectionListener -> {
         selectionListener.getFirstSelectedItem().get().getSubProjects().forEach(project -> {
          xxx.setEnable(¿¿??)
         });
        });

Comment: It's up to you to know what parent/child relations you have, I think you must use the setValue(...all selected nodes...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need something along the lines of this:

```
TreeGrid<String> grid = new TreeGrid<>();
grid.addSelectionListener(e ->
    grid.getSelectedItems().forEach(item ->
        grid.getTreeData().getChildren(item).forEach(grid::select))
);
```

This obviously doesn't cater for deselecting afterwards but is easy to change to do so.

Comment: And how can I deselect elements? How can I know if parent is selected or deselected in order to select/deselect elements? Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: @user2323361 Keep a copy of the List of selected Items and compare it. You'll probably want to pull the event out into its own method.

Comment: Can you give us an example? I tried to do that, but there is no "uncheck" event, and every time "grid::select", call other time to "addSelectionListener" and it's hard to unselect elements. I tried "if (parentList.contains... bla bla bla)" but when I click in child, how can I select parent too? Just an example to do that. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user2323361 Can you add some Code to the question so I can see what it is that you're doing. Doesn't need to be alot. Just enough for me to reproduce the problem properly. I'm at work now but will look over the weekend / this evening.

Comment: @user2323361 And just for the record. It's deselect you're looking for. not uncheck.